# Filtragem de dados pela Url

Tags: javascript, api, url

> No código abaixo estou fazendo uma requisição à api da marvel.

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public`, 
    version: 'Cable',
});

`api.get(`/characters?ts=${ts}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${md5(`${ts}${privateKey}${publicKey}`)}`, {
     params: {
       limit: 20, 
   },`
```

Eu gostaria de saber se há uma forma de passar pela url, ou até mesmo pelos params, um filtro que retornasse todos os personagens que começem com a letra A, por exemplo.

Comment: já consultou a documentação da API? se tiver essa possibilidade vai estar lá

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A própria API da Marvel da esta opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode testar na página:
https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getCreatorCollection_get_0

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Se a Reposta foi útil, aceite-a como tal! hehe